# Injection of one service into another doesn't work in ES6 class

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

When service `UserBookService` gets instantiated I get following error:

> Transition Rejection($id: 0 type: 6, message: The transition errored, detail: ReferenceError: BooksListService is not defined)

My code below. It's written in ES6 and transpiled to ES5 by Babelify for Browserify.

**What's wrong? Why doesn't the injection work in `UserBooksService` constructor?**

As far as I know injection of a service into another service should work simply by declaring it's name as argument in the service constructor. It works for `userBooksDefinition` constant, but doesn't for the service. Injection of `BoooksListService` also works fine in route definition's resolve (*user-books.route.js*).

### user-books.service.js

```
// UserBooksService service definition.

export default class UserBooksService {
  constructor(BooksListService, userBooksDefinition) {
    this.userBooksDefinition = userBooksDefinition;
    this.BooksListService = BooksListService;
  }

  // Get books of given user.
  getUserBooks(user) {
    let userBooksIds = this.userBooksDefinition;
    let userBooksObjects = {};

    // Converts list of books IDs to list of books objects.
    for (var bookIdsListName in userBooksIds) {
      if (userBooksIds.hasOwnProperty(bookIdsListName)) {
        // Fetch and save single list of books.
        let idsList = userBooksIds[bookIdsListName];
        userBooksObjects[bookIdsListName] = BooksListService.getBooks(idsList);
      }
    }

    return userBooksObjects;
  }
}
```

### user-books.module.js

```
// userBooks module.

import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from '@uirouter/angularjs';

import UserBooksService from './user-books.service';
import userBooksComponent from './user-books.component';
import userBooksDefinition from './user-books-definition';
import userBooksRoute from './user-books.route';


export default angular
  .module('app.components.userBooks', [
    uiRouter
  ])
  .config(userBooksRoute)
  .service('UserBooksService', UserBooksService)
  .constant('userBooksDefinition', userBooksDefinition)
  .component('userBooks', userBooksComponent)
  .name;
```

### user-books.route.js

```
// Router configuration for userBooks module.

export default ($stateProvider) => {
  $stateProvider.state({
    name: 'userBooks',
    url: '/user-books',
    views: {
      'content': {
        component: 'userBooks'
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      userBooks: (UserBooksService, BooksListService) => {
        // This injects UserBooksService fine, printing the object to the console.
        console.log(`BooksListService: ${BooksListService}`);
        // TODO: Should get and pass logged in user.
        return UserBooksService.getUserBooks(undefined);
      }
    }
  })
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`BookListService` is now a property of `UserBooksService`. You have to access it with `this`: `this.BookListService`

Comment: Samitier: I was sure it was an injection error, but it's a reference error! Thanks.